# Why we take two focuses in concave and convex lenses before the lens and behind the lens

Tags: optics

[image]        [image]
 we take f(one) and 2f(one) before the lens  and f(two) and 2f(two) behind the lens.

Comment: Do you mean 2F?

Comment: I'm still not absolutely sure what you're asking, but I think it's because concave lenses always produce a virtual image, and (as drawn) a virtual image is always to the left of the lens.

Comment: In plane mirror we use only one focus that is f only but in this case we take two focuses before and two behind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can place an object anywhere you like with respect to the lens. In one diagram, the author simply chose the separation to be twice the focal length. In this case, the rules for ray tracing tell you the image will also happen to be the same distance from the lens. This doesn't work with any other separation.

Also note that the one place you would have trouble placing the object is at the focal point itself. The standard rules for drawing light rays may lead to problems in that case.